infinite scrolling not working in react normally but working when i inspect on google
i m implementing infinite scrolling in react , it's working fine when i inspect but not working normally, can anyone tell me why it's happening and why it's working only when i inspect, i tried some other methods but getting the same problem,used many npm packages but the results are same,is this because of browser or just due to my code,can somebody please tell me why i m encountering this problem and how i can fix it , here is my component code:
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
   import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
   import { useScroll } from '@react-hooks-library/core'
   import useDetectScroll, { Direction } from "@smakss/react-scroll-direction";
   import ReactLoading from "react-loading"; 
   import { SocialIcon } from 'react-social-icons';        
   import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";  

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types 

const Home = ({ url }) => { const navigate = useNavigate();
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const { scrollDir, scrollPosition } = useDetectScroll();
const loader = useRef(null);`your text`
const [end,setend] = useState(false);
const [isloading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = await fetch(url);

    if(res.status !== 200) {
        console.error('Error fetching data');
    }
    const dat = await res.json();
    setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...dat.results]);
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(dat.results);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if(scrollPosition.bottom === 0 && data.length < 40) {
        fetchData();
    }
    else if(data.length >= 40){
        setend(true);
    }
    // getData();      
}, [scrollPosition.bottom,url,data.length < 40]);

const cards = data.map((item, key) => {
    return (
        <div key={key} className="flex  flex-col items-center justify-center bg-white p-4 m-4 border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl ">
            <img src={item.picture.large} alt="profile" className="rounded-full w-32 h-32" />
            <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-black mt-4">{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</h1>
            <h6 className="text-xl font-bold text-black">@{item.login.username}</h6>
            <p className="text-xl text-black mt-1 inline-block"><SocialIcon network='email' bgColor="white" fgColor="black" />{item.email}</p>
            {/* <p className="text-xl text-black">{item.location.city}</p> */}
            <button className="bg-blue-600 text-1xl text-white rounded-lg lg:rounded-xl px-3 py-2 m-10 lg:px-8 lg:py-4 text-bold hover:bg-blue-950">Details</button>
        </div>
    )
});

return (
    <div>
        <header className="sticky top-0 border-b shadow-md min-w-max bg-white flex justify-between z-10">
            <h1 className="text-black font-bold text-2xl lg:text-5xl flex items-center justify-center px-24 lg:px-44">Address Book App</h1>
            <h1>user length: {data.length}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => navigate('/settings')} className="bg-blue-600 text-2xl text-white rounded-lg lg:rounded-xl px-6 py-3 m-10 lg:px-12 lg:py-6 text-bold hover:bg-blue-950">Settings</button>
        </header>
        {isloading ? <div className='flex justify-center items-center pt-20 sm:pt-40'>
            {/* <h1 className='text-5xl text-bold pr-10'>Loading  </h1> */}
            <ReactLoading type={"spinningBubbles"} color="#0D47A1"  height={'20%'} width={'20%'}/>
        </div>
        :
            <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 '>
                {cards}
            </div>
        }
        
        {end && <h1 className='text-center text-3xl lg:text-6xl font-bold'>end of users catalog</h1>}
        <div ref={loader} className="h-10"></div>
    </div>
)

}

export default Home;


Which platform does it not work on? Also, when inspecting your layout, do you see any constraints on your scroll view?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It doesn't work on chrome(desktop) till I inspect my page on chrome. no it's just normal when I inspect and there is no warnings or errors.
